# Use match formula in vba to return a row number

Tags: vba

I have been trying this for quite sometime and although I get the correct answer but I get an `Application-defined or Object defined error`.

I have two sheets: Sheet2 and Sheet3. Both the sheets have a column "url". What I want is to get the row number of the url in Sheet2 and get the urls row position printed in 
Column C ("Match Row") of Sheet3.

This is the example of the data I am working on.
[image: This is the Sheet3 which has url in the column B and Match Row in Column C]
[image: This is the Sheet2 which has url in the column B]

I get the error in this line

```
Matchvalue.Formula = "=Match(Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, 2), Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B:B"), 0)
```

This is what I've tried:

```
Dim i As Integer

i = 2

Do While Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, 2) <> ""

    Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, 14) = 
    WorksheetFunction.Match(Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, 2), 
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B:B"), 0)
    i = i + 1

Loop
```

Comment: Your code does not include the line you say is causing the error.  (And an Excel formula can't refer to objects such as `Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(i,2)` - it uses a completely different syntax such as `Sheet3!B5`)

Comment: Apart from writing to column 14 instead of column 3, doesn't your posted code do what you want?  (It works for me once I get rid of the line breaks which I assume are only part of the posted question rather than in your actual code.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below, explanations inside the code's comments:

```
Option Explicit

Sub MatchUrl()

Dim i As Long
Dim MatchRng As Range

With Worksheets("Sheet2")
    ' set the match range is "Sheet2"
    Set MatchRng = .Range("B1:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
End With

With Worksheets("Sheet3")
    For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        ' check if successful match
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(.Cells(i, 2), MatchRng, 0)) Then
            .Cells(i, 2) = Application.Match(.Cells(i, 2), MatchRng, 0)
        Else ' Match failed, raise some kind of error
            .Cells(i, 2) = "Url not found in Sheet2!"
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't use Match so I don't know the Signature of it but : 
By escaping Quotes perhaps ... like

```
Matchvalue.Formula = "=Match(" & Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, 2) & ";B:B;0)"
```

To escape quotes just double them.

for example `Debug.print "Hey ""You"" how are you ?"`

Comment: You will need to use `Sheet2!B:B` instead of just `B:B`.  (And I'm not sure, but don't you have to use English formula syntax when assigning to the `.Formula` property?  I would have thought the `;`s would therefore need to be `,`s.  But, as I use an English version of Excel, I have no way of checking and so could easily be wrong!)